Crop space from widget in flutter
I'm showing video in Webview and sending video ratio in url but video coming with some left and right white space, Not possible to change in video iFrame. and can't give negative margin so i use transform to provide negative margin, It works only with first item of list and not able to give on right side.
  return  index % 2 != 0 ? Container(
      color:Colors.red,
      transform: Matrix4.translationValues(-40, 0, -80),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
      child: SizedBox(
          height: 140,
          width: 230,
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              return DnaWebViewInterface(
                key: webVideoKey[index],
                url: getDiamondVideoFileUrl(
                  lotId,
                  height: constraints.maxHeight,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                ),
              );
            },
          )),
    ):Container(
      color:Colors.green,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
      transform: Matrix4.translationValues(-40, 0, -60),
      child: SizedBox(
          height: 140,
          width: 230,
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              return DnaWebViewInterface(
                key: webVideoKey[index],
                url: getDiamondVideoFileUrl(
                  lotId,
                  height: constraints.maxHeight,
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                ),
              );
            },
          )),
    );



You can use a combination of SizedBox (or other constraining widgets) and OverflowBox to allow the inner child to overflow inside it.
One example to do that:
SizedBox(
  width: 150, // The actual width you want the widget to appears
  child: OverflowBox(
    alignment: Alignment.center, // Adjust to your need
    maxWidth: double.infinity, // The maximum width you want the inner child to be allowed
    child: TheWidgetToCrop(...),
  ),
)

You can see this article for reference on what widget to use in combination with OverflowBox.
